# Read one file at two different positions simultaneously?

Tags: python-2.7, io

I have a very long file, and I need to read it by processing two different lines at a time. For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for l1 in f1:
        for l2 in f2:
            process(l1, l2)
```

where `process` is some processing function, and `test.txt` is a huge file, so I can't load it all into memory at once.

The code above doesn't work. When `l2` reaches the end of the file, both loops end, as if it only keeps track of a single position in the file, instead of two. How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f2` will be already consumed by the first run once your outer loop reaches the second one.
You'll have to reset it with `f2.seek(0)` after the end of the inner loop.

Try this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f1, open('test.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for l1 in f1:
        for l2 in f2:
            process(l1, l2)
        f2.seek(0)
```